# IntellijIdea plugin dev: Navigate to the source file of a given class in the text editor

Tags: java, intellij-plugin

suppose I have a class name like:

org.myPackage.MyClass

I want to navigate to the source file of that class in the text editor. So far, I know how to open a file in the editor:

```
FileEditorManager fileEditorManager = FileEditorManager.getInstance(project);
VirtualFile vf = LocalFileSystem.getInstance().findFileByPath(myPath);
fileEditorManager.openFile(vf, true, true);
```

I also know how to obtain the source root of a module, so what I'm doing so far is to set myPath to something like:

```
myPath = mainModuleSourceRoot + substituteDotsForSlash("org.myPackage.MyClass")
```

However I want to know if there is a more "IntellijIdea-Plugin oriented" (easier, perhaps more robust) way of opening the source file of a given class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it like this:

```
    GlobalSearchScope scope = GlobalSearchScope.allScope(project);
    PsiClass psiClass = JavaPsiFacade.getInstance(project).findClass("org.myPackage.MyClass", scope);

    if ( psiClass != null ) {
        FileEditorManager fileEditorManager = FileEditorManager.getInstance(project);
        fileEditorManager.openFile(psiClass.getContainingFile().getVirtualFile(), true, true);
    } else {
        //handle the class not found
    }
```

Found the answer in here: https://code.google.com/p/ide-examples/wiki/IntelliJIdeaPsiCookbook#Find_a_Class

---

**Edited answer**

I finally did something like:

```
    GlobalSearchScope scope = GlobalSearchScope.allScope(project);
    PsiClass psiClass = JavaPsiFacade.getInstance(project).findClass(className, scope);

    if (psiClass != null) {
        FileEditorManager fileEditorManager = FileEditorManager.getInstance(project);
        //Open the file containing the class
        VirtualFile vf = psiClass.getContainingFile().getVirtualFile();
        //Jump there
        new OpenFileDescriptor(project, vf, 1, 0).navigateInEditor(project, false);
    } else {
        //Handle file not found here....
        return;
    }
```